# Android/Google Play store: How to find app available in different languages?

Tags: applications, google-play-store, languages, google-play-games

I have a German friend who doesn't speak English. How can he find apps made in Germany using the German language?

Right now for example if he searches "rennen" which means "racing" in english he is shown all racing games in the english language. There has to be developers making apps and games for people in languages other than english, right?

Comment: Changing the country in Google play store, may help?

Comment: There are apps for other languages, but usually the developers include english as main language and german as an additional one, even if they are german.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to see the actual German version of the text, but it kept giving me US English.

Just add &hl=de_DE for Deutsch.
Add &gl=DE&hl=de_DE for the German site in Deutsch.

https://play.google.com/store/apps?hl=de_DE&gl=DE

Comment: Just for clarification: `hl` is for the language used on the Play Store, and `gl` is for geolocation. While this might work in general, it's still not a certain way to find apps that support different languages.